# How to efficiently perform closest neighbor interpolation with Numpy

Tags: numpy, image-processing, numpy-slicing

I have an image that for the sake of this issue is just a numpy array. I want to filter the image to remove noise in form of isolated transparent pixels (more generally, I also would like to remove lines, but this the next problem).

Let's set a playable example:

```
a = np.ones((10, 10), np.uint8)
a[5,5] = 0    # isolated hole
a[5,6] = 2    # the neighbour to clone
```

Leading to this matrix:

```
       [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Well, the problem is that when there is a 0 in the matrix, I want it to be replaced by the closest neighbour (2 in this case, but perhaps an average of the four, if easy to implement, would be better).

Can this be done without explicit loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect the `0` entries in `a` using [boolean array indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing). To calculate the described average, use [`scipy.signal.convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) with `mode='same'` and the following kernel:

```py
kernel = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]) / 4
```

Finally, replace the found `0` entries in `a` with the corresponding entries from the convolution result. See this code snippet:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

a = np.ones((10, 10), np.uint8)
a[5, 5] = 0
a[5, 6] = 2
print(a)

kernel = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]) / 4
b = convolve2d(a, kernel, mode='same')
a[a == 0] = b[a == 0]
print(a)
```

The result is:

```
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Since you initialized `a` as `np.uint8`, the actual replacing value `1.25` is truncated to `1`. If you initialize `a` as `np.float32`, you'll see, that `1.25` is correctly placed there.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
NumPy:         1.20.1
SciPy:         1.6.0
----------------------------------------
```

---

**EDIT:** The hardcoded kernel won't work correctly for corner and border pixels, if you just wanted to calculate the average of the only two/three neighbours. Maybe, set up the kernel without the division, and store three different convolution results, each divided by `2`, `3`, or `4` and pick the correct values w.r.t. the presence of corner, border, or regular pixels.

Comment: Great, thanks for the fast answer. I understand how this works and it makes a lot of sense. But this raises one picky question... The convolution is carried out EVERYWHERE, albeit actually exploited in a handful of holes. This sounds inefficient as hell. It'd be wiser to calculate the convolution only AFTER and WHERE the holes have been found. I think this leads to a deeper question rooted in the way Numpy is implemented, but I couldn't help it not to mention it here. Thanks again!

Comment: For large images, and a small amount of single `0` entries, of course, that might be faster: First find the `0` entries, iterate the corresponding regions of interest (ROIs), and only convolve these ROIs appropriately. But, at first glance, I can't think of a solution without using some kind of loop for that - which you wanted to avoid.